# Jquery and search form problem

Tags: jquery

I can't get my jquery code to clear my search form when a user clicks in the search field can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Jquery

```
$('#text').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("title")) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}).blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("title"));
    }
});


$("#searchForm").submit(function() {
    $("#text").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == this.title) {
    $(this).val("");
    }
    });
});
```

html5 code

```
<header id="header">
<div id="header-con">
    <h1>
        <a href="" title=""><img src="" alt="" /></a>
    </h1>

    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>a href="" title=""></a></li>
            <li>a href="" title=""></a></li>
            <li>a href="" title=""></a></li>
            <li>
                <form method="post" action="" id="searchForm">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="text" name="search" size="38" value="Search..." title="Search..." id="text" />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" id="sbutton" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>             
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: `<header id="header">` could probably remove that id :-) Plus the existing markup is missing the `<` on the opening anchor tag. Although that's not the problem. This works fine for me.

Comment: are you really putting this all inside the head tag? *body* is there for a reason

Comment: @naveen inside the header tag not the head tag.

Comment: +1: i am sorry anom. you code is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using HTML5, why aren't you using the [`placeholder` attribute](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder)?

```
<input type="text" name="search" size="38" placeholder="Search..." id="text" />
```

...and done. No JavaScript.

Comment: I forgot about that attribute but I still would like to solve my Jquery problem.

Comment: The Placeholder Attribute is currently not or not correctly supportet by many browsers. The JS Version caught that issue imho in an elegant way… But you could use both. So the JS Version is the Fallback for not supported browsers.

Comment: @gears this is a solved problem. http://forrst.com/posts/Placeholder_functionalities_for_non_supported_br-tfh and http://www.kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/jquery-html5-placeholder-fix/ and [many others](http://www.google.com/search?&q=modernizr+placeholder)

Comment: Yes… and i know :) But only if you use the Modernizr lib.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are not binding your event handlers on [`$(document).ready(...`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), so those elements are probably not present at the time the handlers are attached. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // your event handler code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you use $("#text").each(...), if only one same identifier was possible?

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function() {  
    $("#text").val("");
    returh false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. You just need to bind your event handler, when the document is ready...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("title")) { $(this).val(""); } 
    }).blur(function () { if ($(this).val() == "") { $(this).val($(this).attr("title")); } });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my Plugin to solve your issue:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gvs4Y/2/

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    cc_value: function(options) {

        // Set Plugin defaults
        var defaults = {};

        // Set options
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            // Cache options to shorter variable to access Options by o.myOption
            var o = options;

            // Cache $(this) Object to var obj
            var obj = $(this);

            // Save default Value to Data Attrirbute
            obj.data('defaultValue', obj.val());

            // Bind Events to given Object. Clear input or direct select user input value
            obj.bind('focus mouseup', function(e) {
                if (($(this).val()) === (obj.data('defaultValue'))) {
                    $(this).val('');
                } else {
                    // Select Value Text if it changed from default
                    this.select();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });  

            // If the Focus is lost by bluring and nothing is changed restore the default value
            obj.blur(function() {
                newValue = jQuery(this).val();
                if (newValue === '') {
                    $(this).attr('value', jQuery(this).data('defaultValue'))
                }
            }); 
        });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Function call:

```
jQuery('YOUR SELCTOR').cc_value();
```

- Works with all specified Text-Inputs
- Nice Usabilty Improvements (Text marked if different form original value)